# Query to list table with different column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql query to view data from a table:

```
SELECT created, name, surname, phone, email, address
FROM jos_registration_form
ORDER BY created DESC
```

This returns a list in the front of a table with first column name created, second column name name, third column name surname and so on.

Is there an sql statement that can change the column names to something else (not in the mysql database) only in the front?

For example to view in the front for the first column name created, the greek Δημιουργία, for the second column name name, the greek Όνομα and so on.

I know that this can be done with php etc, but I'd like to do it with sql.

Comment: You mean... an alias for the column names?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the name as an alias to the sql statement:

```
SELECT created Δημιουργία, name Όνομα,surname,phone,email,address
FROM jos_registration_form ORDER BY created DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this. You can find documents if you search for `alias in sql`

```
SELECT Created AS CreateDate FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I must to agree with acceptable answer

You can use alias to change the column name at result

```
SELECT created AS Δημιουργία, 
       name AS Όνομα,
       surname, phone, email,address
FROM jos_registration_form ORDER BY created DESC
```